# sed: match 'var = var' and delete

Tags: regex, assembly, sed

I'd like to use sed to delete lines from files that contain the pattern `myvar = myvar`.  So, for instance, the assembly files I'm editing contain lines like:

`wmemcopy = wmemcopy`

I tried the sed command:

`sed '/^\([a-z]*\) = \1$/d'`

But that command is failing to find and remove those lines.  Is there a sed command for accomplishing this?

Edit:

If I try the command with `sed -i '/^\([a-z]*\) = \1$/d' wtent.s` the lines are not removed.  This is the file I'm attempting this command on:

```
    .file   1 "wtent.c"
    .section .mdebug.abi32
    .previous
    .gnu_attribute 4, 1
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  updwtmp
    .hidden updwtmp
    .set    nomips16
    .ent    updwtmp
    .type   updwtmp, @function
updwtmp:
    .frame  $sp,32,$31      # vars= 0, regs= 3/0, args= 16, gp= 0
    .mask   0x80030000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-32
    move    $6,$0
    sw  $17,24($sp)
    sw  $31,28($sp)
    move    $17,$5
    sw  $16,20($sp)
    li  $5,9            # 0x9
#APP
 # 40 "libc/misc/utmp/wtent.c" 1
    .set    noreorder
    li  $2, 4005            # open
    syscall
    .set    reorder
 # 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    move    $16,$2
    beq $7,$0,$L2
    sw  $2,errno
    j   $L1
$L2:
    bltz    $2,$L1
    move    $4,$2
    li  $5,1            # 0x1
    jal lockf
    bne $2,$0,$L1
    move    $4,$16
    move    $5,$17
    li  $6,384          # 0x180
#APP
 # 43 "libc/misc/utmp/wtent.c" 1
    .set    noreorder
    li  $2, 4004            # write
    syscall
    .set    reorder
 # 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    beq $7,$0,$L6
    sw  $2,errno
$L6:
    move    $4,$16
    move    $5,$0
    move    $6,$0
    jal lockf
    move    $4,$16
#APP
 # 45 "libc/misc/utmp/wtent.c" 1
    .set    noreorder
    li  $2, 4006            # close
    syscall
    .set reorder
 # 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
$L1:
    lw  $31,28($sp)
    lw  $17,24($sp)
    lw  $16,20($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,32
    j   $31
    .end    updwtmp
    .size   updwtmp, .-updwtmp
    .globl  updwtmp
    updwtmp = updwtmp
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.7.0"
```

Comment: Your command works for me. I recommend using `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `[a-z]` to avoid issues with your locale, but it works for me also with `[a-z]`.

Comment: @BenjaminW.  I edited my question to show the file I'm attempting this on.  Does it work for you on that file?  The line `updwtmp = updwtmp` remains for me.

Comment: Well, that line starts with a blank, but you anchor your pattern at the beginning of the line with `^`, so the line doesn't match.

Comment: Nice.  Thanks.  That's it.  I needed a \s at the beginning.